# A method for finding elements (i.e xpath,id etc..) for building UITests in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

How do I find elements (i.e xpath,id etc..) for building UITests in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below two way:

1. Open your Application page using the test case and give a debug 
   point. Then on debug console search for that element you want to.
   Example you are looking for an element. First try with like p print
   (app.buttons.debugdescription) or (app.textviews.debugdescription) 
   etc etc.
2. Use Appium for that. Though it uses different application rather 
   than XCode but it working like charms. I personally use Appium for 
   finding the id.xpaths,views,classes etc and then Implement it in 
   XCUITest.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance,

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about element type, you could use the command below to print out XPath.

```
p print(app.debugdescription)
```